# Avoiding Wordpress .htaccess rules on specific folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress installed in root and a particular folder not related to Wordpress. I created a .htaccess file for the particular folder, but it is not working. The Wordpress .htaccess is always been called.

Wordpress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Particular folder .htaccess:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/folder/start.php http://www.domain.com/folder/index.php
```

When I load the above old address (that does not exists), the Wordpress .htaccess is called, instead of use the folder's .htaccess to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple `.htaccess` you can put all the rules on the WordPress main `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Use either:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/start\.php$ /folder/index.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Or

```
Redirect 301 /folder/start.php http://www.domain.com/folder/index.php
```

Don't forget to change `folder` to your actual folder name.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation, but the 301 redirection is not occuring. It is redirecting to the 404 page. The paths are right. :-/

Comment: are both files in the same folder ? or different folders ?

Comment: start.php does not exist anymore. index.php in the folder. And the .htaccess is in the root.

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti have you tried accessing `http://www.domain.com/folder/index.php` directly and it works? Also have you noticed I have added an extra rule to your WordPress rule on my above answer?

Comment: Yes, http://www.domain.com/folder/index.php is working. I put the extra rule, but I'm still getting the 404. I know that start.php doesn't exist, but the .htaccess should do the redirection, and not show me a 404 page.

Comment: @MarioLimaCavalcanti OK so give this a try instead of using your `Redirect` use this `RewriteRule ^folder/start\.php$ /folder/index.php [L,R=301,NC]` **____OR____** `Redirect 301 /folder/start.php http://www.domain.com/folder/index.php`

Comment: Hey, thanks! The second suggestion works for me. `Redirect 301 /folder/start.php http://www.domain.com/folder/index.php`