# htaccess conflicts in root folder and sub directory folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a php site in the root folder with an htaccess. I have a blog in a subfolder but the wordpress blog is not loading because of the blog htaccess is conflicting with the htaccess in the root folder.

Here is the two htaccess files

Root Folder

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /lasercap/public_html/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
#Map http://www.example.com/x to /jekyll/x unless there is a x in the web root.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lasercap/public_html/

RewriteRule ^ISHRS2013$ ISHRS2013.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lasercap/public_html/$1

#DirectoryIndex /lasercap/public_html/site-offline.html index.html
DirectoryIndex /lasercap/public_html/index.php
```

htaccess for Wordpress Blog

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/failed_auth.html$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help with htaccess. i need your help. Thank you

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660088/avoiding-wordpress-htaccess-rules-on-specific-folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw the answer. I thought it is bit difference from that. Because i want to redirect the blog folder which under the root folder. But the blog folder is not loading.

Comment: just rename .htacess of wordpress and check if it works

Comment: you want to say that, i will change the .htaccess to .{something else}.

Comment: just remane it to 0.htaccess anc check if blog folder works